# UITextView Alternative

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nslayoutconstraint

As i understood from Apple docs attributedText property of UITextView:

> This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font, textColor, and textAlignment properties so that they reflect the style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

Therefore i cannot add an attributedString by code with multiple Attributes at different locations.

Can someone please help me create the following effect by code in iOS6? This is possible using nib files and by changing range attributes for text parts in UITextView but i cant seem to reproduce the effect by code.

<'font systemFontOfSize=18>**Desired**<'/font> **effect** <'textColor = [UIColor redColor]> **to be written b**<'/textColor>**y code**.

Suppose the tags correspond to attributes.

P.S. I don't want to use CATextLayers since i am trying to use the AutoLayout feature with the UITextView.

Comment: Have you seen DTCoreText: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText ?

Comment: I support this message! (being the maintainer of this fine project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build an NSAttributedString with an NSDictionary containing all of the attributes you need:

```
NSAttributedString* attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
               initWithString: @"Desired effect to be written by code" 
                   attributes: (NSDictionary*)attributes];
```

Or use it's mutable subclass NSMutableAttributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  
               initWithString: @"Desired effect to be written by code"];

    [attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                      value: [UIColor redColor] 
                      range: NSMakeRange(15,15)];
```

...etc
then...

```
myTextView.attributedText = attString;
```

Each attribute is applied to an NSRange (location, length) of the string. Distinct attribute types (eg colour, font size) can overlap different ranges.

**update**
Use the NSMutableAttributedString example. `NSAttributedString's initWithString:attributes` will apply attributes across the entire range of the string, which is what you are trying to avoid, sorry for confusion.

Comment: The problem i have is like follows:
I have a UITextView subclass with 3 NSMutableAttributedString properties. I am appending attributed strings to these properties at given stages of the application and after each append operation i change the attributedText of the UITextView subclass to the property i used to append a new attributed string on.

If i do an NSLog on the properties i see attributes coming from the NSAttributedStrings i appended, but setting the attributedText after that operation to the property i used does not have the same effect as the code you posted above. Any ideas why?

Comment: Just figured what the problem was by returning again to Apple docs from what i wrote in my first question. 
Assigning a new value to this ... the values in the font, textColor, and textAlignment properties so that they reflect the style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string. 
Therefore, the solution for me was to provide each of the NSAttributedStrings i am appending their attributes and make sure not to leave then attributes array blank. 
Thank you for you help @hewas