# Different font size in the same label?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont

Is it possible to have different fontsize or weight in the same UILabel? I can do it in the storyboard as Attributed label, but I need to do it programmatically.

```
cell.lblOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"FontSize15:: %@, FontSize20:: %@",monkey, goat];
```

Edit: I saw something about NSAttributedString but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at my answer here:

[UITextView Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932550/uitextview-alternative/13933012#13933012)

- make an NSMutableAttributedString
- give it some attributes (applied to ranges of characters)
- set the label's attributedText property

.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attString = 
                              [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithString: @"monkey goat"];

[attString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value: [UIColor redColor]
                  range: NSMakeRange(0,6)];


[attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                  value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]
                  range: NSMakeRange(0,6)];

[attString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                  value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:24]
                  range: NSMakeRange(7,4)];

self.label.attributedText  = attString;
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the range just for the first %@ in the string? Or i need to count the words in the string to get the correct range? Made sens? :)